# Why should we use Jasmine Spy Object in Angular Unit Testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-jasmine

I have a query regarding Angular unit testing using Jasmin/Karma.

I have 3 services as below: EmployeeService, SalaryService and TaxationService.

EmployeeService depends on SalaryService which is injected in it's constructor.

SalaryService depends on Taxation service which is again injected in it's constructor.

In my employee.component.spec.ts, I have the below code:

```
let employeeService: EmployeeService;
let salaryServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<SalaryService>;

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 providers: [EmployeeService],
 declarations: [ EmployeeComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();
  employeeService = TestBed.inject(EmployeeService);
  salaryServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(SalaryService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SalaryService>;
}));

it('should return Name and Salary', () => {
  expect(employeeService.getEmployeeNameAndSalary(1)).toBe("John Smith receives: $12345 and tax value of 15%");
});
```

The code works fine, my question is why do we need to use Jasmine Spy - the code works fine without the spy service as well?

```
 salaryServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(SalaryService) as jasmine.SpyObj<SalaryService>;
```

I have used the below as reference: https://angular.io/guide/testing-services.

If below example is more clear, what is the need to create the ValueServiceSpy? Does the TestBed.inject not already inject all dependencies and the 'dependencies of the other dependencies'?

[image]

Comment: as explained later on on the angular guide, the spy is used in a test. As you don't use it, you don't need to define it yourself. A spy role is to 'spy' a service. If somewhere in MasterService you call a function from ValueService, you can use this spy to check if the function was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain, I also had similar questions few years back :

**Why should we use Jasmine Spy Object in Angular Unit Testing?**

Answer: Because when you create `spy` , you get the power to do below tasks in unit tests:

1. You can check whether the function has been called or not (by using `expect(component.method).toHaveBeenCalled())
2. You can even override the actual implementation (written inside `service.ts`) and return some dummy data to create several scenarios for unit test cases.

You check this [article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49) where I used Stubs unlike what you can see in angular guide. I used `Stubs` because I can reuse it other `other-component.spec.ts` which uses the same service, by simply injecting in `providers` using `useClass`.  Take your time and see how I used `.toHaveBeenCalled()` [ to understand my **point 1** ] , and also how I used [.returnValue()](https://gist.github.com/shashankvivek/db16fbdea28f8b1041d3ed50f73cf2e7#file-students-component-spec-ts-L3) to recreate the `error` behavior of service.

---

**What is the need to create the ValueServiceSpy? Does the TestBed.inject not already inject all dependencies and the 'dependencies of the other dependencies'?**

Answer: Yes, `TestBed.inject` did inject the dependencies but it injects the actual `ValueService`. For unit testing you want to isolate the " **service which you want to test**  " (*in this case, you want to test `MasterService` and not `ValueService`*) .

So, it makes sense to **`mock`** the `ValueService` while testing `MasterService`.

---

Does that make sense ?